# Typekit Font Events aren't helping with Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC)

Tags: javascript, html, css, typekit

I resolved the FOUC using font events.  I've hidden `p, h1, h2, a, span` using `visibility: hidden` with some javascript at the footer of the page, and then in the typekit `active` event it sets them back to `visible`.

This solution works fine in my local environment and in production it seems to work fine when doing a page reload.  But it doesn't work when clicking around from page to page in production (screencast: http://screencast.com/t/m8YQwFNNsrv)

I believe the difference being that when clicking around from page to page the browser cache is leveraged.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a race condition. The web font response is evaluating (from cache) before you reach the page bottom where your JS to hide those elements executes, but by then has no effect.

I've always found it better just to let the FOUC happen instead of working around the many edge cases if web fonts ultimately fail to load and you're hiding content.

Comment: Hm - I'll try to see if I can catch that race condition.  

I'm actually thinking for now I may just revert back to having typekit in the <head> non-asynchronous - the FOUC gets pretty annoying after a while.

Comment: Okay so it looks like this is actually an issue with the Wistia embed that we're using.  Will post details when I hear back.